# APK / Decrypting

Tags: android, decryption, java, apk

I'm new to Reverse Engineering, so I apologize if something is wrong.
There is a free program that requires a license key, which can no longer be bought and obtained. I'm trying to write a KeyGen or just change key parameters like other people have done. It seems they just changed the date in the key and it began to work. I also have a real license key, but if you open it in a text document or Notepad++ - Non-Cyrillic Standard is displayed there.

I looked at the source code of the program, I realized that initially the key is created in .dat, encrypted via AES / CBC / PKCS5Padding, I have BasePassword, SecretKeySpec, parameters for which a license key, and IV can be created. I wrote Keygen,  but generated with the wrong number of bytes. The original key is 192 bytes, mine is about 160. Help me with Java sample of decrypting/keygen based on this crypto.class source code :

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.crypto.BadPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.Cipher;
import javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException;
import javax.crypto.NoSuchPaddingException;
import javax.crypto.spec.IvParameterSpec;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;

public class Crypto {
  private static final String C2BKEY = "DEFAULTC2BKEY";
  
  private static final String CRYPTO = "CRYPTO";
  
  private static final String DATE = "ExpirationDate";
  
  private static final String EMAIL = "Email";
  
  public static final String FILENAME_AUTHORIZATION = "/authorization.dat";
  
  private static final String FILENAME_TIME = "/validation.dat";
  
  private static final String FULLNAME = "Fullname";
  
  private static final String HOST_NAME = "pool.ntp.org";
  
  private static final String LEVEL = "Level";
  
  private static int authorizationStatus;
  
  private static byte[] backuptEncryptedByte;
  
  private static String basePassword = "BasePassword";
  
  private static String strDecryptedKey;
  
  private static String str1Level;
  
  private static String strEmail;
  
  private static String strExpDate;
  
  private static String strFullName = "";
  
  private static String str2Level;
  
  private static String str3Level;
  
  private static String strLevel;
  
  private static String str4Level;
  
  private static String str5Level;
  
  private static String str6Level;
  
  private static String str7Level;
  
  static {
    strEmail = "";
    strLevel = "";
    strExpDate = "";
    str2Level = "0";
    str3Level = "0";
    str4Level = "0";
    str5Level = "0";
    str6Level = "0";
    str7Level = "0";
    str8Level = "0";
    backuptEncryptedByte = null;
    authorizationStatus = 0;
  }
  
  public static String decrypt(byte[] paramArrayOfbyte, String paramString) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "decrypt");
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(generatePassword(paramString).getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(2, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
    return (new String(cipher.doFinal(paramArrayOfbyte))).trim();
  }
  
  public static String decryptDeviceKey(byte[] paramArrayOfbyte) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "decrypt");
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("secretkeyspec".getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(2, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
    return (new String(cipher.doFinal(paramArrayOfbyte))).trim();
  }
  
  public static void deleteAuthenticationKey(String paramString) {
    File file = new File(paramString + "/authorization.dat");
    if (file.exists())
      file.delete(); 
    authorizationStatus = 0;
    strFullName = "";
    strEmail = "";
    strLevel = "";
    strExpDate = "";
  }
  
  public static byte[] encrypt(String paramString) throws IOException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, NoSuchPaddingException, InvalidKeyException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, IllegalBlockSizeException, BadPaddingException {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "decrypt");
    SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec("SecretKeySpec".getBytes("UTF-8"), "AES");
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
    cipher.init(1, secretKeySpec, new IvParameterSpec(new byte[16]));
    return cipher.doFinal(paramString.getBytes("UTF-8"));
  }
  
  private static String generatePassword(String paramString) {
    String str = "";
    for (byte b = 0; b < 4; b++)
      str = str + (String)basePassword.subSequence(b, b + 1) + paramString.subSequence(b, b + 1); 
    return str + (String)paramString.subSequence(4, paramString.length());
  }
  
  public static int getAuthStatus() {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "getStatus");
    return authorizationStatus;
  }
  
  public static String getDate() {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "getDate");
    return strExpDate;
  }
  
  public static String get2() {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "get2Level");
    return str2Level;
  }
  
  public static String get3Level() {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "get3Level");
    return str3Level;
  }
  
  public static String get4Level() {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "get4Level");
    return str4Level;
  }
  
  public static String getLevel() {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "getLevel");
    return strLevel;
  }
  
  public static String get4Level() {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "get4Level");
    return str4Level;
  }
  
  public static String get5Level() {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "get5Level");
    return str5Level;
  }
  
  public static String get6Level() {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "get6Level");
    return str6Level;
  }
  
  public static String get7Level() {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "get7level");
    return str7Level;
  }
  private static byte[] loadTime(String paramString) {
    byte[] arrayOfByte;
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "load time");
    File file = new File(paramString + "/validation.dat");
    String str = null;
    if (!file.exists())
      return null; 
    paramString = str;
    try {
      FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream();
      paramString = str;
      this(file);
      paramString = str;
      byte[] arrayOfByte1 = new byte[(int)file.length()];
      arrayOfByte = arrayOfByte1;
      fileInputStream.read(arrayOfByte1);
      arrayOfByte = arrayOfByte1;
      fileInputStream.close();
      arrayOfByte = arrayOfByte1;
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
      iOException.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return arrayOfByte;
  }
  
  public static byte[] m_loadExternalAuthenticationKey(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
    byte[] arrayOfByte;
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "load external key");
    String str = null;
    File file = new File(paramString2);
    if (!file.exists())
      return null; 
    paramString1 = str;
    try {
      FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream();
      paramString1 = str;
      this(file);
      paramString1 = str;
      byte[] arrayOfByte1 = new byte[(int)file.length()];
      arrayOfByte = arrayOfByte1;
      fileInputStream.read(arrayOfByte1);
      arrayOfByte = arrayOfByte1;
      fileInputStream.close();
      arrayOfByte = arrayOfByte1;
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
      iOException.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return arrayOfByte;
  }
  
  public static byte[] m_loadInternalAuthenticationKey(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
    byte[] arrayOfByte;
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "load internal key");
    File file = new File(paramString1 + "/authorization.dat");
    paramString2 = null;
    if (!file.exists())
      return null; 
    paramString1 = paramString2;
    try {
      FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream();
      paramString1 = paramString2;
      this(file);
      paramString1 = paramString2;
      byte[] arrayOfByte1 = new byte[(int)file.length()];
      arrayOfByte = arrayOfByte1;
      fileInputStream.read(arrayOfByte1);
      arrayOfByte = arrayOfByte1;
      fileInputStream.close();
      arrayOfByte = arrayOfByte1;
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
      iOException.printStackTrace();
    } 
    return arrayOfByte;
  }
  
  public static void m_saveAuthenticationKey(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "m_saveAuthenticationKey");
    backuptEncryptedByte = null;
    backuptEncryptedByte = m_loadInternalAuthenticationKey(paramString1, "");
    byte[] arrayOfByte = m_loadExternalAuthenticationKey(paramString1, paramString2);
    if (arrayOfByte != null)
      saveKey(paramString1, arrayOfByte); 
  }
  
  private static void parseDecryptedString(String paramString) {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "parse string");
    authorizationStatus = 0;
    if (strDecryptedKey != null && !strDecryptedKey.equals("")) {
      Date date1;
      String[] arrayOfString2 = strDecryptedKey.split(";");
      for (int i = 0; i < arrayOfString2.length; i = j + 1) {
        int j;
        if (arrayOfString2[i].contains(":")) {
          String[] arrayOfString = arrayOfString2[i].split(":");
          j = i;
          if (arrayOfString.length == 2)
            if (arrayOfString[0].compareTo("Fullname") == 0) {
              strFullName = arrayOfString[1].trim();
              Util.print("CRYPTO", strFullName);
              j = i;
            } else if (arrayOfString[0].compareTo("Email") == 0) {
              strEmail = arrayOfString[1].trim();
              Util.print("CRYPTO", strEmail);
              j = i;
            } else if (arrayOfString[0].compareTo("Level") == 0) {
              strLevel = arrayOfString[1].trim();
              Util.print("CRYPTO", strLevel);
              j = i;
            } else {
              j = i;
              if (arrayOfString[0].compareTo("ExpirationDate") == 0) {
                strExpDate = arrayOfString[1].trim();
                Util.print("CRYPTO", strExpDate);
                j = i;
              } 
            }  
        } else {
          j = i;
          if (i < arrayOfString2.length - 1)
            if (arrayOfString2[i].compareTo("Level 2") == 0) {
              str2Level = arrayOfString2[i + 1];
              Util.print("CRYPTO", str2Level);
              j = i + 1;
            } else if (arrayOfString2[i].compareTo("Level 3") == 0) {
              str3Level = arrayOfString2[i + 1];
              j = i + 1;
              Util.print("CRYPTO", str4Level);
            } else if (arrayOfString2[i].compareTo("Level 4") == 0) {
              str4Level = arrayOfString2[i + 1];
              j = i + 1;
              Util.print("CRYPTO", str5Level);
            } else if (arrayOfString2[i].compareTo("Level 5") == 0) {
              str5Level = arrayOfString2[i + 1];
              j = i + 1;
              Util.print("CRYPTO", str6Level);
            } else if (arrayOfString2[i].compareTo("Level 6") == 0) {
              str6Level = arrayOfString2[i + 1];
              j = i + 1;
              Util.print("CRYPTO", str6Level);
            } else if (arrayOfString2[i].compareTo("Level 7") == 0) {
              str7Level = arrayOfString2[i + 1];
              j = i + 1;
              Util.print("CRYPTO", str7Level);
            } else {
              j = i;
              if (arrayOfString2[i].compareTo("Level 8") == 0) {
                str8Level = arrayOfString2[i + 1];
                j = i + 1;
                Util.print("CRYPTO", str8Level);
              } 
            }  
        } 
      } 
      arrayOfString2 = null;
      Date date2 = null;
      SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat(Global.DATE_FORMATTER);
      try {
        date1 = simpleDateFormat.parse(paramString);
        date2 = date1;
      } catch (ParseException parseException) {
        parseException.printStackTrace();
      } 
      String[] arrayOfString1 = arrayOfString2;
      try {
        Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(strExpDate);
        date1 = date;
        System.out.println(date);
        date1 = date;
        if (date2.after(date1)) {
          Util.print("CRYPTO", "Authorization Expired");
          authorizationStatus = 0;
          return;
        } 
      } catch (ParseException parseException) {
        parseException.printStackTrace();
        if (date2.after(date1)) {
          Util.print("CRYPTO", "Authorization Expired");
          authorizationStatus = 0;
          return;
        } 
      } 
    } 
  }
  
  public static void restoreKey(String paramString) {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "restoreKey");
    deleteAuthenticationKey(paramString);
    if (backuptEncryptedByte != null)
      saveKey(paramString, backuptEncryptedByte); 
  }
  
  private static void saveKey(String paramString, byte[] paramArrayOfbyte) {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "m_save Key");
    File file = new File(paramString + "/authorization.dat");
    try {
      FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream();
      this(file);
      fileOutputStream.write(paramArrayOfbyte);
      fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
      fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
      iOException.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }
  
  private static void saveTime(String paramString1, String paramString2) {
    Util.print("CRYPTO", "save time");
    File file = new File(paramString1 + "/validation.dat");
    try {
      FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream();
      this(file);
      fileOutputStream.write(paramString2.getBytes("UTF-8"));
      fileOutputStream.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException fileNotFoundException) {
      fileNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException iOException) {
      iOException.printStackTrace();
    } 
  }
}
```